# How can I quickly earn money after the story is over?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've finished all the story missions, and most of the side-quests, but there's still several properties I can't afford yet. Some of these properties cost tens of millions of dollars, but I can't find a way to quickly earn that money. I'm aware there's always the option of playing the stock market, but that's a crap shoot after all of Lester's assassination missions are done.

Are there any reliable ways to quickly earn the money needed to buy the more expensive properties? Do the options differ for each character?

Comment: I don't think there are major money making schemes after beating the game except the Lester's assassination missions esp if you want  to buy golf course which is 150 million dollars.

Comment: Provided you have some cash, you can play the stock market. The best way to do so is follow some of the larger forums on the internet and take their advice.

http://www.reddit.com/r/GTAMarket/ has a number of threads, broken down by platform on what stocks are currently paying out the best.

Comment: IGN had an article a while ago showing which stocks that never go down. It's your only option as far as I know - sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but as the old saying goes - you have to spend money to make money. If you buy the best properties you can afford, you will get their income.

Answer (score -2):

Redo the game maybe. Once your done with the last heist, place it all in stock. Sell it after a really long time. This isn't quick, but it will get you what you want